# PHP ElasticSearch parent child relation ship mapping and indexing

Tags: php, elasticsearch, mapping, parent-child

Suppose I have a document named as `participant_tests`, and a child type named as `participant_test_question_answers`, in my case I should always index `participant_tests` before creation and mapping of its child `(participant_test_question_answers)`.
I have bellow mapping for child type:

```
protected $mappingProperties = array(
    'index' => 'my_index',
    'type' => 'participant_test_question_answers',
    'body' => [
        "participant_tests" => [],
        'participant_test_question_answers' => [
            '_source' => [
                'type' => 'string',
                'analyzer' => 'standard'
            ],
            "_parent" => [
                "type" => "participant_tests"
            ],
            'properties' => [
                'id' => array("type" =>  "string"),
                'participant_test_qu_id' => array("type" =>  "string"),
                'bank_answer' => array(
                    'type'          => 'nested',
                    "properties"    => array(
                        "id"            => array("type" => "string"),
                        "test_answer_text_en"       => array("type" => "string"),
                        "test_answer_text_pr"       => array("type" => "string"),
                        "test_answer_text_pa"       => array("type" => "string"),
                        "correctness"   => array("type" => "string"),
                        "is_selected"   => array("type" => "string"),
                    )
                ),
                'created_at' => array(
                    'type' => 'date',
                    "format"=>"YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss||YYYY-MM-dd||MM/dd/yyyy||yyyy/MM/dd"
                ),
                'updated_at' => array(
                    'type' => 'date',
                    "format" => "YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss||YYYY-MM-dd||MM/dd/yyyy||yyyy/MM/dd"
                ),
                'deleted_at' => array(
                    'type' => 'date',
                    "format" => "YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss||YYYY-MM-dd||MM/dd/yyyy||yyyy/MM/dd"
                ),
                'created_by' => array(
                    'type' => 'nested'
                ),
                'updated_by' => array(
                    'type' => 'nested'
                ),
                'deleted_by' => array(
                    'type' => 'nested'
                )
            ]
        ]
    ]
);
```

Now when i want to index the child type, it shows below error:

```
 $client4testAnswer = ClientBuilder::create()->build();
 // Update the index mapping
 $client4testAnswer->indices()->putMapping($questionTestAnswerObject->getResourceMapping());
 $qTstAnswerParams = [
     "index"  => "my_index",
     "type"   => "participant_test_question_answers",
     "id"     => uniqid(),
     "parent" => $participant_test_doc_id,
     "body" => [
        // body content
     ]
];
$client4testAnswer->index($qTstAnswerParams);
```

And this function return the mapping array:

```
function getResourceMapping(){
    return $this->mappingProperties;
}
```

Error:

```
BadRequest400Exception in Connection.php line 663:
MapperParsingException[Root type mapping not empty after parsing! Remaining 
fields: [participant_tests : []] [participant_test_question_answers : 
{_source={type=string, analyzer=standard}, _parent={type=participant_tests}, 
properties={id={type=string}, participant_test_qu_id={type=string}, 
bank_answer={type=nested, properties={id={type=string}, test_answer_text_en=
{type=string}, test_answer_text_pr={type=string}, test_answer_text_pa=
{type=string}, correctness={type=string}, is_selected={type=string}}}, 
created_at={type=date, format=YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss||YYYY-MM-
dd||MM/dd/yyyy||yyyy/MM/dd}, updated_at={type=date, format=YYYY-MM-dd 
HH:mm:ss||YYYY-MM-dd||MM/dd/yyyy||yyyy/MM/dd}, deleted_at={type=date, 
format=YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss||YYYY-MM-dd||MM/dd/yyyy||yyyy/MM/dd}, created_by=
{type=nested}, updated_by={type=nested}, deleted_by={type=nested}}}]]
```

don't know why ?
Is its mandatory that mapping of parent child should be created before any indexing of parent or child ?

Comment: Can you please provide a version of elasticsearch you use?

Comment: I have solved this by deleting index and adding relation ship in index creation time (before adding docs) to index.